# Function to share waze link on whatsup or gmail?

Tags: react-native

I’m trying setting up a waze feature that shares the link of the place itself .

this function use for open the waze app..

```
handleWazeLocation = (address, lat, lng) => {
        let ll = lat + "," + lng;
        this.waze.setll = ll;
        this.waze.setSearchQuery = address;
        console.log(this.waze);
        this.waze.open()
    };
```

and here button that open waze..

```
<Button
 buttonType={'default'}
 onPress={() => this.handleWazeLocation(address, lat, lng)}>
```

I need a function (button) same like that function that let me share the location of waze in the whatssup or Gmail and that will be fired in the onpress.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at Deep Linking and both apps have their own URL scheme.

Firstly, you need to modify your `handleWazeLocation` function by performing the following:

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native'; 

handleWazeLocation = (...) => {
  // Rest of your code
  Linking.openURL(); // You need to pass the URL scheme depending on WhatsApp/Gmail
}
```

**WhatsApp**

You can find the WhatsApp documentation [here](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/iphone/23559013).

To open WhatsApp with Hello World, you would need to open `whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!`.

**Gmail**

For Gmail, you will need to send the following, as found [here](https://www.macstories.net/links/gmail-for-ios-url-scheme/)

```
googlegmail:///co?subject=<subject text>&body=<body text>
```

---

Edit: This is an update as of Mon 26th April 2020

You should check that your app can open the URL before you attempt to open it, this will handle any errors with apps not being installed on Users devices.

You can do this with `canOpenURL` from Linking.

```
const handleLink = async (url) => {
  const canOpenURL = await Linking.canOpenURL(url);

  if(canOpenURL) {
    Linking.openURL(url);
  }
}

handleLink('whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!');
```